# Making a branch in git for some big code changes

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I am making some changes to some ETL code and want to make sure I don't break anything.
I have a git repo and all of the files I am working on have been committed and stored on Bitbucket. (`git push origin master`)

I believe that I should be making a new branch, correct? Will this reflect on Bitbucket as well or do I have to push it there somehow?

```
git branch config_changes
```

Now when I make some edits to my files will I just say the following?

```
git checkout config_changes
git add filename.py
git commit -m "changes"
git push origin config_changes
```

That will backup my changes to Bitbucket. Now, when I feel like the code is ready to replace my existing code, I just do:

```
git checkout master
git merge config_changes
git push origin config_changes
```

Or should that last line be `git push origin master`?

Bonus question: I have Windows Task Schedule running .py files to automate some daily stuff. I want to make changes to files but keep the tasks running on the current (working) .py files. Is there a way to accomplish this? The task manager is pointing directly to a filename. Do I duplicate the folder for now?

Comment: After merging into `master`, push the `master` branch, not the branched you merged with.

Comment: Yes, duplicate the folder if you want to have two branches concurrently on your machine.  You could even add a `git pull` to your scheduler so that it automatically keeps its copy up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that big changes should be done in a remote branch. After you commit your first change to the dev branch and push it, you'll see the branch appear in BitBucket.

```
git checkout -b config_changes
*make changes*
git add filename.py
git commit -m 'message'
git push origin config_changes
```

The `-b` flag in `git checkout` tells git that you're creating a new branch from the current working branch (in your case, master).

When merging, you're on the right track but you should indeed `git push origin master`. It is also good practice to `git pull origin master` to ensure your master copy is in sync with the repository (for when others are working on the same project).

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge config_changes
git push origin master
```

Comment: **Note:** A `pull` will fetch latest remote references and *merge them with your local branch.* IF you don't want to keep your local changes to the `master` branch (in theory, you don't work on this branch - only merge into it - depending on your branching structure), you can fetch the latest references and force a reset (so that your local branch will be the same as the one on the remote server (bitbucket)). `git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master`.

Comment: Cool, I'll try this out. How do people solve for scheduled tasks running a specific file? If I make changes to that file then there is a chance I will break it (this happened today). Git seems helpful to have historical records and being able to revert, but I can't seem to think of how this will help modifying files without really making a new copy with a different name or in a different folder.

Comment: Have the scheduled files run from the `master` branch. Just before the schedule task runs the files, do `git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master` - assuming you want the most recent version that is on remote `master` branch to run (ie: discard all local edits, and use what's been committed to the `master` branch)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I will implement this.